# Get form names from three project in listbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have three projects (project 1, project 2 and project 3) all in one solution.
Each project has its own windows forms (C#). I am writing my code in project 3.
What i want is to list all projects forms names in one list box:
Here's my code:

```
private void GetFormNames()
{
    foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(a.FullName);
        foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
        {
            if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
            {
                Form f = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                string FormText = f.Text;
                string FormName = f.Name;
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add("" + FormText + "//" + FormName + "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'am getting this error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: Error message is very clear IMO..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
(Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

It implied that the class t have a constructor with no parameter in it.
One of your form must not have a parameterless constructor, that's why you have the exception.

You could test it before calling CreateInstance like

```
if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
```

Or even better:

```
if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
{
    var emptyCtor = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    if(emptyCtor != null)
    {
        var f = (Form)emptyCtor.Invoke(new object[]{});
        string FormText = f.Text;
        string FormName = f.Name;
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add("" + FormText + "//" + FormName + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I have an additional clarification, the result i am getting isn't satisfying: the function returns exact form names of current project but not for other projects i.e(In other projects i have form1, form2, form3 etc.. what i am getting is "Select window", print preview etc...)